# Using OpenGL on Raspberry Pi Jessie

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

I am trying to get some simple graphics working on my Raspberry Pi Jessie with C++.  I am getting my [instructions from this website.](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial01/tutorial01.html)

I have installed the following libraries:

`apt-get install g++ freeglut3-dev glew1.5-dev libmagick++-dev libassimp-dev libglfw-dev`

And there appeared to be no errors there. I have the following code:

```
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

static void RenderSceneCB()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

static void InitializeGlutCallbacks()
{
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderSceneCB);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(1024, 768);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Tutorial 01");

    InitializeGlutCallbacks();

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

And compiled it using the following command:

`g++ window.cpp -lGL -lGLU -lglut -o window`

After a few tries and fixing a couple of errors (I'd gotten the include folder wrong for freeglut.h)  I now get this when I try and  run the program:

`freeglut (compiled/window) failed to open display ''`

Which gives me no indication where I am going wrong, how to fix it, or even where to start! What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Did you start an X server and lauch the program from within the X session? If you didn't you have to do this. The error you're getting indicates that the program tries to connect with an X session, but doesn't find one in it's environment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12456622)

Comment: @kerem: Well, it might actually be the answer: If OP didn't start an X session this error might appear.

Comment: @datenwolf thanks, could you modify the above code to do this? Or does command lines to achieve that?

Comment: @Chud37: The X server a separate process running; it's currently still the state of the art for enabling graphics output in Linux (Wayland is making good headway, though). So either configure your R-Pi to start a X display manager (xdm, lxdm, or similar). Or start an X session with `startx`, and then from there launch your OpenGL program. *Or start an X session with your program being the primary X client: `xinit ${ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_YOUR_PROGRAM}`